# Non-linear ODE $xy' - y = e^{y'}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Could not found appropriate method to solve this non-linear first order diff. equation.
$$
xy'-y = e^{y'}
$$

Thanks for help

Comment: Hint:Differentiate both side with respect to $ x $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p = \frac{dy}{dx}$. Therefore the given differential equation is,
$$xp-y=e^{p}$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ gives,
$$p+xp'-p=e^{p}p'$$
$$\therefore p'=0 \implies p=C$$ When we plug this in our initial expression, we get $y=Cx-e^C$
The other solution is,
$$x=e^p \implies p = \ln x$$
Plugging this in our initial expression,
$$y=x\ln x-x$$ which is the singular solution.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

$$xy'-y = e^{y'}$$
$$y=xy'- e^{y'}$$
It's of the form:
$$y=xy'+f({y'})$$
This is   [Clairaut's differential equation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation)